# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 - Error on PDO Insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Having some problems with my first time using PDO. Getting an error after this insert:

```
   <?php 

require_once '_dbconnect.php';

// Attempt insert query execution
try{
    // Create prepared statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `entrysubmissions` (boxnum, entryname, entryemail) VALUES (:boxnum, :entryname, :entryemail );";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':boxnum', $_REQUEST['entryboxid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':entryname', $_REQUEST['entryname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':entryemail', $_REQUEST['entryemail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Entry Submitted Successfully.";
    print $_REQUEST['entryboxid'];
    print $_REQUEST['entryname'];
    print $_REQUEST['entryemail'];

    $conn->exec($sql);

    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "Records inserted successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;

} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

 // Close statement
unset($stmt);

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

I am getting an error, but the row is being inserted successfully. I must be doing something obvious wrong, but I can't spot it. The correct values are being inserted into the table.

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO `entrysubmissions` (boxnum, entryname, entryemail) VALUES (:boxnum, :entryname, :entryemail );. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':boxnum, :entryname, :entryemail )' at line 1
```

Help would be gratefully accepted. I've really tried, but today it seems I've failed at googlefu.

Comment: How do you create the value of `$conn`?

Comment: please provide value of insert params

Comment: @NigelRen:
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe:
$_REQUEST['entryboxid'] = 73
$_REQUEST['entryname'] = sadf
$_REQUEST['entryemail'] = a+@a.com

Comment: Can you also show us how you're executing the query? As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong in the above code. And since you say that the values _does_ get inserted, I'm suspecting that you might try and execute the query more than once.

Comment: "_Could not able to execute ..._" doesn't sound like a "regular" error message, does that appear in your code somewhere?

Comment: You have `$stmt->execute();` and then later, you have `$conn->exec($sql);` (which is most likely what throws the error). Remove the last `$conn->exec($sql)`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've added the full file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson --- ding ding ding, you solved it. (internal sigh) Many many thanks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - how do I mark your comment as the solution? Can you post a solution below?

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to execute the query twice.

```
// First here
$stmt->execute();

echo "Entry Submitted Successfully.";
print $_REQUEST['entryboxid'];
print $_REQUEST['entryname'];
print $_REQUEST['entryemail'];

// Then again here
$conn->exec($sql);
```

Remove the last one:

```
$conn->exec($sql);
```

and you should be set.

Comment: +10.  looks to me like that line is a leftover, from converting from dynamic sql vulnerable to sql injection, into code using prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Comment: Thank you @Magnus!! What a goof. 

Answer (score 0):

Your code in fine, Just Remove  **$conn->exec($sql);** from your code, you are executing twice, that's why you are getting an error.

Comment: I have edited my answer, sorry but I'm new so I was not aware where to write comments.

Comment: No problem, @spencer7593 I'm not here to raise points I'm here to help peoples :)

Comment: @FurqanAnsari:  I appreciate the effort. The edit to the answer is a big improvement, but for the next huge improvment, remove that huge block of code that no one needs to read. It looks like its a copy of code already in the OP... but is someone supposed to compare that, line by line, this code block to OP code block, to see what changes were made?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @spencer7593, you are right there were no need to paste the whole code, I thought that will be easier for him, that's why I did that.

Comment: my downvote is removed, and answer is now upvoted +10